# Scatter plot of two columns for a FeatureCollection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, chart

I have some SNPP-FIRMS data in a FeatureCollection format. I would like to make a scatter chart of two of its columns (FRP Value, and Date). I tried but it did not give me a correct chart which does not show anything (see the screenshot).

[image: Uncorrect scatterchart])

I do not know why! I am not sure if it’s because of the format of the values of two columns (FRP: Float, and Date: Long).

Here is my code:

```
var viirs = ee.FeatureCollection('VIIRS_4Mar_21Oct_2018_T')

var Viirs_FRP = viirs.select('FRP');

var Viirs_Date = viirs.select('ACQ_DATE');

var chart_s = ui.Chart.feature.byProperty ({
     features: viirs, 
     xProperties: ['Viirs_FRP'], 
     seriesProperty:'Viirs_Date'
})
    .setChartType('ScatterChart')
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Fire Radiative Power (MW) per time (VIIRS)',
      hAxis: { title: 'DATE'},
      vAxis: { title: 'FRP VALUE CHANGE' },
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3
});
print(chart_s);
```

Comment: Try the `ui.Chart.feature.byFeature` chart instead: `ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(viirs, 'Viirs_FRP', 'Viirs_Date')`. For a better response, please share the FeatureCollection asset.

Comment: Thanks, @jdbcode, but as I know 'ui.Chart.feature.byFeature' is used when you have two feature collection. However, I tried and it does not work! and here is my shared asset: [https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/havalali005/FC]